# How to use Laravel Blade template engine if there's no contextual escaping?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

By default, Blade escapes everything as html, and it seems like there are no other options.

Here's one example where this can be a problem:

```
// We have URL that contains some user input.
$url = "https://exaple.com/path?userInput1=USER_INPUT&userInput2=USER_INPUT";

// Let's render it in the Blade template.
<a href="{{ $url }}">URL</a>

// This prevents XSS but messes up the output.
<a href="https://exaple.com/path?userInput1=USER_INPUT&amp;userInput2=USER_INPUT">URL</a>
```

[Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/escape.html), for example, supports all those escaping strategies:

- `html`: escapes a string for the HTML body context.
- `js`: escapes a string for the JavaScript context.
- `css`: escapes a string for the CSS context. CSS escaping can be applied to any string being inserted into CSS and escapes everything except alphanumerics.
- `url`: escapes a string for the URI or parameter contexts. This should not be used to escape an entire URI; only a subcomponent being inserted.
- `html_attr`: escapes a string for the HTML attribute context.

What's with Blade? Is there at least any library that provides this functionality?

Comment: I think `{{ $url }} `  won't changes `&` for `&amp`. Anyway, you should use `{!! $url !!}` for not-escaping

Comment: @AlexAngelico it actually changes, at least Laravel 8. If you just output unescaped URL with the user input, you will be vulnerable to XSS, so it's not gonna work.

Comment: Then I didn't understand your question, you can escape with `{{ }}` or not escape with `{!! !!}`. About XSS, it's a security issue, IMO not related to the escaping. You need to use same origin policy to address XSS as far as I know, or some kind of authentication.

Comment: Blade decorative `{{ }}` makes a sub call to a method which ineffectively just calls [`htmlentities()`](https://3v4l.org/NjeNT) on the string. Touching what @AlexAngelico said - do not use `{!! !!}` with untrusted user input. You should look to use pretty URL's instead of trying to build GET parameters into your URI's. Remember, secure by design..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found so far.

- `html`: `{{ $var }}` works perfectly fine for escaping in the HTML body context
- `js`: for javascript Laravel has `Js::from($var)` helper. It should prevent js code injection and it also preserve types, so it can be used like this: `const _var = {{ Js::from($var) }};`
- `html_attribute`: you can escape the output using `{{ $var }}` or sanitize the output. I didn't find any sanitizer that Laravel provides for this purpose, as an option you can look at [the one from Twig](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/09760aa6892cfcb6c7af78c0a6316d506cebde6c/src/Extension/EscaperExtension.php#L321)
- `url`: URL is actually a tough one. If the browser is the only consumer of your HTML, it's ok to escape it. Modern browsers can handle it. If this doesn't work for you, what you might want to do is parse the URL first and then URL encode each URL component (e.g by using `rawurlencode`). But keep in mind that PHP built-in functions for URL parsing are [not entirely safe](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Tsai-A-New-Era-Of-SSRF-Exploiting-URL-Parser-In-Trending-Programming-Languages.pdf) so it makes sense to look at some 3rd party libraries.